# Мне нужна документация по методу VK API

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Из вопросов на сайте я понял, что существует метод в вк, позволяющий редактировать админов в чате, а именно `messages.setmemberrole`. Так вот, мне нужно понять, что в этот метод входит и как это ставить :)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, данным методом:

```
vk_session.method('messages. messages.setMemberRole',
                                      {'peer_id': '',
                                       'role': 'admin',
                                       'member_id': ''})
```

Comment: Еще бы не помешала ссылка на документацию (любую, не обязательно официальную), а то как-то ваш ответ не отвечает на вопрос с заголовком "Мне нужна документация по методу VK API"

Comment: по этому методу нет документации его нет на офф сайте даже

Comment: Но где-то же он описан, вы же не из головы его взяли?

Comment: https://github.com/vknet/vk/issues/1031 все, что могу предоставить, а что вам еще надо от этого?